specifying an elimination matrix
This question comes from Gilbert Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra.

Given matrix
$$ 
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
1&1&0 \\ 
4&6&1 \\ 
-2&2&0 
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
create $3$ elimination matrices $E_{21}$, $E_{31}$, and $E_{32}$ such that $E_{32}E_{31}E_{21}A = U$, an upper triangle matrix.

I understand how to specify $E_{21}$ and $E_{31}$ by taking $a_{21}/a_{11}$ and $a_{31}/a_{11}$ respectively, reversing the sign and then inserting these values into the identity matrix in the position you want to zero out.
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&0&0 \\ 
-4&1&0 \\ 
0&0&1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&0&0 \\ 
0&1&0 \\ 
2&0&1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Using the same process for $E_{32}$, the scalar $a_{32}/a_{22}$ leads to
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&0&0 \\ 
0&1&0 \\ 
0&-\frac{1}{3}&1 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which fails to produce the right matrix.
The answer key says to use $-2$ instead of $-\frac{1}{3}$ in the $(3,2)$ position of $E_{32}$. What is the process for finding the $-2$ directly from $A$ in order to specify $E_{32}$?

The elimination matrices are being used in succession, forming a sequence
$$
A \;\mapsto\; E_{21}A 
\;\mapsto\; E_{31}E_{21}A 
\;\mapsto\; E_{32}E_{31}E_{21}A = U.
$$
So at each stage of the algorithm, you have to look at the result thus far in order to specify the next step. In particular, the $\color{green}{(2, 2)}$ and $\color{red}{(3, 2)}$ entries that determine the scalar for the final step are read off from the matrix
$$
E_{31}E_{21}A 
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \color{green}{2} & 1 \\
0 & \color{red}{4} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So in this case the ratio is $\dfrac{\color{red}{4}}{\color{green}{2}} = \color{blue}{2}$ and the final elimination matrix in the sequence is
$$
E_{32} 
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \color{blue}{-2} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that
$$
U = E_{32}E_{31}E_{21}A 
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note: The reason that you didn't notice your slight error in understanding the algorithm at the second step is because the first step only modified the second row and the coefficient for the second step only involves the first and third rows. This is a general phenomenon: when using a pivot to clear out the column below it, those particular steps are independent of one another and so all of their coefficients can be calculated at once and those particular steps can be done in any order.
